# CUDA invalid resource handle error when allocating gpu memory buffer

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I am faced with cuda invalid resource handle error when allocating buffer on gpu.

1, I download the code from `git clone https://github.com/Funatiq/gossip.git`.

2, I built this project in the gossip directory: `git submodule update --init && make`. Then I got the compile binary excute here.

3, then I generate a scatter and gather plan for my main GPU, here, it is 0.

```
$python3 scripts/plan_from_topology_asynch.py gather 0

$python3 scripts/plan_from_topology_asynch.py scatter 0
```

then it generates scatter_plan.json and gather_plan.json.

4, finally, I execute the plan:
`./execute scatter_gather scatter_plan.json gather_plan.json`

The error was pointing to these lines of [code](https://github.com/Funatiq/gossip/blob/4b7f6428ce59660751b04679a6be58a2a43a05cf/executor.cuh#L396):

```
std::vector<size_t> bufs_lens_scatter = scatter.calcBufferLengths(table[main_gpu]);
    print_buffer_sizes(bufs_lens_scatter);

    std::vector<data_t *> bufs(num_gpus);
    std::vector<size_t> bufs_lens(bufs_lens_scatter);
    TIMERSTART(malloc_buffers)
    for (gpu_id_t gpu = 0; gpu < num_gpus; ++gpu) {
        cudaSetDevice(context.get_device_id(gpu)); CUERR
        cudaMalloc(&bufs[gpu], sizeof(data_t)*bufs_lens[gpu]); CUERR
    }
    TIMERSTOP(malloc_buffers)
```

The detailed error is shown as:

```
RUN: scatter_gather
INFO: 32768 bytes (scatter_gather)
TIMING: 0.463872 ms (malloc_devices)
TIMING: 0.232448 ms (zero_gpu_buffers)
TIMING: 0.082944 ms (init_data)
TIMING: 0.637952 ms (multisplit)

Partition Table:
470 489 534 553 514 515 538 483
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Required buffer sizes:
0 538 717 604 0 344 0 687

TIMING: 3.94455e-31 ms (malloc_buffers)
CUDA error: invalid resource handle : executor.cuh, line 405
```

For reference, I attached the complete error report [here](https://github.com/Funatiq/gossip/issues/6). The curious part is that the author cannot reproduce these error on his server. But when I ran it on DGX workstation with 8 GPUs. This error occurs. I doubt if it is cuda programming error or environment specific issues.

Comment: If I were working on this, the first thing I would want to do is try to reproduce the problem.  If I can't reproduce the problem, then there is no way that I can confirm or validate that anything I might say would actually fix anything.  For this reason, SO pretty much expects that you provide a [mcve] in the question itself, for questions like this.  See item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), not use of the word "must".  There is no doubt this can take some work for a large code base like this, but without it your question is basically off-topic.

Comment: The way your question is written right now, I don't even really know what steps to follow.  At a minimum, I would expect from you: 1. I downloaded this code here (exact commands).  2.  I built the code (exact commands)  3. I ran the code this way (exact commands). 4. These were the results I got.  5.  These were the results I was expecting.   Without anything except item 4, it's not a very actionable question, IMO.

Comment: Hi @RobertCrovella Sorry for the confusing question that I have made. I have updated the question to reproduce the error for this project. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has a defect in it, in the handling of `cudaEventRecord()` as used in the `TIMERSTART` and `TIMERSTOP` macros defined [here](https://github.com/gravitino/cudahelpers/blob/a9d821c43de91a4fbb756c71e14ae18e09823813/cuda_helpers.cuh#L46) and used [here](https://github.com/Funatiq/gossip/blob/master/executor.cuh#L393) (with the `malloc_buffers` label).

CUDA events have a [device association](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#stream-and-event-behavior), impliclitly defined, when they are created.  That means they are associated with the device selected by the most recent `cudaSetDevice()` call.  As stated in the programming guide:

> cudaEventRecord() will fail if the input event and input stream are associated to different devices.

(note that each device has its own null stream - these events are being recorded into the null stream)

And if we run the code with `cuda-memcheck`, we observe that the invalid resource handle error is indeed being returned by a call to `cudaEventRecord()`.

Specifically referring to the code [here](https://github.com/Funatiq/gossip/blob/master/executor.cuh#L393):

```
...
std::vector<size_t> bufs_lens(bufs_lens_scatter);
TIMERSTART(malloc_buffers)
for (gpu_id_t gpu = 0; gpu < num_gpus; ++gpu) {
    cudaSetDevice(context.get_device_id(gpu)); CUERR
    cudaMalloc(&bufs[gpu], sizeof(data_t)*bufs_lens[gpu]); CUERR
}
TIMERSTOP(malloc_buffers)
```

The `TIMERSTART` macro defines and creates 2 cuda events, one of which it immediately records (the start event).  The `TIMERSTOP` macro uses the timer stop event that was created in the TIMERSTART macro.  However, we can see that the intervening code has likely changed the device from the one that was in effect when these two events were created (due to the `cudaSetDevice` call in the for-loop).  Therefore, the `cudaEventRecord` (and `cudaEventElapsedTime`) calls are failing due to this invalid usage.

As a proof point, when I add `cudaSetDevice` calls to the macro definitions as follows:

```
    #define TIMERSTART(label)                                                  \
        cudaEvent_t timerstart##label, timerstop##label;                       \
        float timerdelta##label;                                               \
        cudaSetDevice(0); \
        cudaEventCreate(&timerstart##label);                                   \
        cudaEventCreate(&timerstop##label);                                    \
        cudaEventRecord(timerstart##label, 0);
#endif

#ifndef __CUDACC__
    #define TIMERSTOP(label)                                                   \
        stop##label = std::chrono::system_clock::now();                        \
        std::chrono::duration<double>                                          \
            timerdelta##label = timerstop##label-timerstart##label;            \
        std::cout << "# elapsed time ("<< #label <<"): "                       \
                  << timerdelta##label.count()  << "s" << std::endl;
#else
    #define TIMERSTOP(label)                                                   \
            cudaSetDevice(0); \
            cudaEventRecord(timerstop##label, 0);                              \
            cudaEventSynchronize(timerstop##label);                            \
            cudaEventElapsedTime(                                              \
                &timerdelta##label,                                            \
                timerstart##label,                                             \
                timerstop##label);                                             \
            std::cout <<                                                       \
                "TIMING: " <<                                                  \
                timerdelta##label << " ms (" <<                                \
                #label <<                                                      \
                ")" << std::endl;
#endif
```

The code runs without error for me.  I'm not suggesting this is the correct fix.  The correct fix may be to properly set the device before calling the macro.  It seems evident that either the macro writer did not expect this kind of usage, or else was unaware of the hazard.

The only situation I could imagine where the error would not occur would be in a single-device system.  When the code maintainer responded to your issue that they could not reproduce the issue, my guess is they have not tested the code on a multi-device system.  As near as I can tell, the error would be unavoidable in a multi-device setup.

Comment: Big thanks to Robert. You always help us on cuda programming.

Comment: Hi Robert, I am still curious why there is no error when running the all2all [code](https://github.com/Funatiq/gossip/blob/master/executor.cuh#L276).

Comment: I don't know how to run the all2all code.  But if it is using the same macros, and you fixed the macros, then that code may be fixed also.  You would want to start with the code base that is broken for the above test.

Comment: In default, when I was running all2all. There is no such issue. The difference from gather& scatter is to generate all2all plan  `$python3 scripts/plan_from_topology_asynch.py all2all 0` and then execute using the new plan `./execute all2all all2all_plan.json`. I followed what you did to add two `cudaSetDevice` into macro definitions but there were still the same errors. I am looking into if I missed something or not.

Comment: I forward your answer to the maintainer. He already fixed the issues. Thanks Robert.